# Implementing an Equals Button for JavaScript Calculator

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create an equals button for a Javascript calculator. I am not sure why the function I have is not working. I believe it has something to do with making a variable equal to the output of a function. I know that the compute() function works because I can do all of the calculations. Small side question, my operations buttons are not displaying on the calculator display screen. Unsure why because it is the same as the numbers function which works correctly. I believe somehow I am incorrectly accessing the innerText. Operations buttons are logging to the console.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
        <button data-delete>DEL</button>
        <button data-operand>÷</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operand>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operand>+</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operand>-</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>

</div>
```

````
const del = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operand = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operand]');
const equals = document.querySelectorAll('[data-equals]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.slice(0, -1)
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if (this.currentOperand.includes('.') && number === '.') return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand + number
        console.log(this.currentOperand)
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === '') return
        if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
        console.log(operation)
    }

    compute() {
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)

       if (this.operation === '÷') {
        this.currentOperand = prev / current
       } else if (this.operation === '*') {
        this.currentOperand = prev * current
       } else if (this.operation === '+') {
        this.currentOperand = prev + current
       } else if (this.operation === '-') {
        this.currentOperand = prev - current
       }
    }

    equal() {
        this.currentOperand = this.compute()
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
        console.log(this.currentOperand)
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
        this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand
    }
}


const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

number.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operand.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

del.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator.equal()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})```
````

Comment: I will suggest you to debug your code and mention the code where you facing issues!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `addEventListener` on a array from all elements with attribute `data-equals`. I suggest you changing the logic of that you assign the listener.

You can just put the `addEventListener` call in the `equals.forEach` function:

```js
// above is the current code without equals.addEventListener call...

// The below code iterates all equal buttons and do addEventListener on all from them
equals.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculator.equal()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})
```

Or you can simply change the variable `equals` with your elements:

Change the top declaration of variable from it:

```js
// your code above...
// there is no querySelectorAll, I changed it to querySelector
const equals = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
// your code below...
```

I think it should work. The main problem that you trying to assign listener to an array.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. So to clarify, the problem is I am creating an array with only one element which is somehow confusing JS? It works above when I have an array with multiple elements such as const number = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')

Comment: @Pete1230z Yes. The problem is that you call addEventListener on array object.